# org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error listenerStart

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I am trying to start my web application on Tomcat 7, but whenever I click on the start button, I get this error:

> FAIL - Application at context path /Web could not be started

and below lines are added to `catalina.log` file:

> Feb 08, 2012 7:21:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal SEVERE: Error listenerStart Feb 08, 2012 7:21:01 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
>   [/Web] startup failed due to previous errors

How is this caused and how can I fix it?

Comment: what are the previous errors :  startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: @Mike: they are not always visible in the IDE console/log file. I'm unsure as to the why, it seems to be a combination of certain Eclipse version, certain server plugin make/version and certain Tomcat version.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I had a similar problem.
The catalina.out logged this log Message

Apr 17, 2013 5:14:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart

**Check the localhost.log in the tomcat log directory** (in the same directory as catalina.out), to see the exception which caused this error.

Comment: In my case, it was more like localhost.2013-06-06.log, so default log viewer in IDEA did not show what the problem was

Answer (score 12):

> *SEVERE: Error listenerStart*

This boils down to that a `ServletContextListener` which is registered by either `@WebListener` annotation on the class, or by a `<listener>` declaration in `web.xml`, has thrown an unhandled exception inside the `contextInitialized()` method. This is usually caused by a developer's mistake (a bug) and needs to be fixed. For example, a `NullPointerException`.

The full exception should be visible in webapp-specific startup log as well as the IDE console, *before* the particular line which you've copypasted. If there is none and you still can't figure the cause of the exception by just looking at the code, put the entire `contextInitialized()` code in a `try-catch` wherein you log the exception to a reliable output and then interpret and fix it accordingly.

Comment: i am facing the very same problem , can you please a bit more i can try-catch on the contextInitialized() , because the log is only giving a vague message that i cannot interprete as a programmer.
as additional information this probleme occured after obfuscation with proGuard , i made sure to update the web.xml applicationContext.xml as well as other config xml .

Answer (score 4):

For Intellij Idea sometime localhost.log file generated at different location. For e.g. you can find it at homedirectory\ .IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat.

IF you are using spring then start ur server in debug mode and put debug point in catch block of org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext's refresh() method. If bean creation fails you would be able to see the exception.

Answer (score 2):

I faced exactly the same issue in a Spring web app. In fact, I had removed spring-security by commenting the config annotation:

```
// @ImportResource({"/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml"})
```

but I had forgotten to remove the corresponding filters in `web.xml`:

```
<!-- Filters --> 
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Commenting filters solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It can be due to a number of reasons happening when configuring the listener. Best way is to log and see the actual error. You can do this by adding a `logging.properties` file to the root of your classpath with the following contents:

`org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Please, check your DB password, mine seem to have been caused by its expiration.

Answer (score -1):

Select "all project" and right click

> Maven-> Update project